# Issue reading QueryString parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, query-string

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.
Currently I'm having a relatively simple issue but I just can't figure out what's going on.

Basically I have a function which calls the getJson jQuery API passing this URL

```
var url = '../../xx/xx/GetCollectionAgencyData?clientIdIn=' + 
        baseModel.clientId + '&documentNumber=' + self.documentNumber;
```

I can tell the call is being routed correctly beacuse the breakpoint on the Controller gets hit inside the GetCollectionsAgencyData

The problem I'm having is that for whatever reason when I debug the Controller method I can see the value of the clientIdIn param is passed properly but the documentNumber parameter is passed as null... If I debug the JS I can also see that the self.documentNumber correctly contains the value that I want to pass to the server.

This is the signature of the method on the Controller

```
public CollectionAgencyDataDto GetCollectionAgencyData(int? clientIdIn, 
                          int? documentNumber){}
```

Any ideas why the documentNumber is not being passed correctly from the Client to the Server?

Comment: Are you sure the `documentNumber` type is actually a `int?`.  Without more, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: It's possible that your routes are out of order. The one specifying the `documentNumber` parameter needs to be above the one specifying only the `clientIdIn` parameter, as the first route to match is the one that is used.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see this coming... It was a Type issue... @Greg thanks to you I notice I was actually sending the value as a String which was causing the whole thing to go wrong... Thanks for pointing it out (Y) Have a great day everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJson("../../xx/xx/GetCollectionAgencyData", 
{ 
    clientIdIn: baseModel.clientId, 
    documentNumber: self.documentNumber // ensure your sending this is an int not string!
}, 
function(response){
// Success logic...
});
```